# Extended version of the paper "Consistent Hashing and Random Trees" with proofs

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, randomized-algorithms, hash-function, cache-oblivious

I've been reading the following paper:

- David Karger, Eric Lehman, Tom Leighton, Rina Panigrahy, Mathew Levine, Daniel Lewin, "[Consistent Hashing and Random Trees: Distributed Caching Protocols for Relieving Hot Spots on the World Wide Web](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/258533.258660)", 1997. [pdf](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/technical-publication/consistent-hashing-and-random-trees-distributed-caching-protocols-for-relieving-hot-spots-on-the-world-wide-web-technical-publication.pdf)

In the paper the authors mention that 
the proofs will be available in the "full paper". 
But I cannot find any extended version of the paper with proofs.
Can someone direct me to a version with the proofs?

Comment: Email the authors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I found that the authors never published an extended version with proofs.

The closest thing to an extended paper is,

> Rina Panigrahy. **Relieving hot spots on the worldwide web**. 1997. [1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.17.8503&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

which was the Master's thesis of Rina Panigrahy (under Prof. Karger & Prof. Smith), who's also a co-author of the paper under discussion.  It is a good, detailed reference to the original paper with all the proofs I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/9947#files is what you are looking for.